# Strings in android/java, replace() does nothing

Tags: java, android, string, replace, space

In android/java, I'm trying to replace the space in some strings with a `+`, but it doesn't seem to work. Am I doing it wrong?

```
String string="Hello world";
string.replace(" ", "+");
```

Comment: I assume it is just for this example, but I just want to point out that I wouldn't name a variable "string"....

Comment: if you are doing this for url encoding purposes, take a look at the URLEncoder class

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`String` objects are immutable, so the `replace` method doesn't change the string but creates a new one that you have to re-save:

```
String string="Hello world";
string = string.replace(" ", "+");
```

Comment: +1 Exactly. `String.replace` returns a string. It is an accessor, not a direct mutator.

Comment: @jor - if this is the correct answer, check the box next to it so @Cristian gets credit.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, the StringBuffer class provides a mutable string. The replace method will return the same object.